# Series of requests - (canceled) requests - Angular HttpClient

Tags: angular, rest, rxjs

I encountered a strange issue related to series of HTTP GET from `HttpClient` using Angular v7.

I have an array of some `Items`, and for each number, I would like to request the API. The whole mechanism is working fine if the array is not as big, if it's above 10 approximately then in `chrome dev tools` I see that all requests are `(canceled)`

the code is like this:

```
const nextDataSource = [];

const dataUpdate$ = from(this.dataSource).pipe(
      mergeMap(item => this.api.getNextItems(item).pipe(
        map(result => ({items: result, item: item})),
        tap((result: { items: Item[], item: Item }) => this.updateDataSource(result, nextDataSource)),
      )),
      finalize(() => {
        this.dataSource = [...nextDataSource];
      })
    );

this.subscription.add(dataUpdate$.subscribe());
```

It's strange but if I add a delay for example `delay(10)` in this pipe the requests are not being canceled?

How to stop this, prevent cancelation? I don't want it at all!

Comment: gona need to recreate this issue in a blitz

Answer (score 0):

I encounter something similar before if subsequent request is triggered too fast
try pause in between

```
from(this.dataSource).pipe(
   concatMap(item =>timer(500),item=>item), 
   ....
```